# How do find active element in Intern

Tags: intern

According to the documentation linked from the Intern Git project (https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/doc/api.md) it should be possible to use active() to obtain the active element on the page...

However, when I use this I don't see my callback or fired or get any output, e.g...

```
.keys(specialKeys.Tab)
.sleep(1000)
.active(function(err, element) {
   console.log("Active Element is: ", err, element);
})
```

However I'm not seeing any output at all, nor any error conditions... I am however seeing the tab event occurring. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The functional API in Intern is Promise-based, so you don’t pass callbacks into any of the methods except for `then`, `otherwise`, or `always`. [Step 4 of the Intern tutorial](https://github.com/theintern/intern-tutorial#step-4-write-a-functional-test) describes this in more detail. Your code would be:

```
.keys(specialKeys.Tab)
.sleep(1000)
.active()
.then(function(element) {
   console.log("Active Element is: ", element);
})
```

Comment: That was actually something I tried (and have just tried again)... but  I don't see the console.log logged to my output.

Comment: However... this *does* work:  .keys(specialKeys.Tab)
            .sleep(1000)
            .active()
            .text()
            .then(function(resultText) {
               console.log("Test #1a");
               expect(resultText).to.equal("Column 1", "The text is incorrect");
            })